# solr: facet search multivalued field containing the same value multiple times

Tags: json, solr

I have a field like this in my solr document (in JSON):

```
someField = [Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4,...];
```

I want to know how many documents there are containing each of those values.

The facet search I am executing works but there is one problem: The values represent a hierarchy (denoted by the sequence) and the same value could appear on different levels in the hierarchy (representing a different entity).

E.g.

```
(in document1) someField = [Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4];
(in document2) someField = [Value1, Value3, Value4, Value5];
(in document3) someField = [Value1, Value3, Value3, Value4];
```

So my result should looke like this:

```
Value1 = 3
Value2 = 1
Value3 = 2 (level 2)
Value3 = 2 (level 3)
Value4 = 1 (level 3)
Value4 = 2 (level 4)
Value5 = 1
```

On inserting the documents, I can see that inserting

```
Value1, Value3, Value3
```

is inserted correctly (Solr doesn't convert this into  `Value1, Value3`)

How can I achieve this for the faceting, i. e. make Solr treat each level of `someFiled` separately and not count all `Value3` as one field?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A token is a token when it comes to faceting.

You can however use a secondary field and add metainformation to your tokens when indexing (from your own code), that contain the level the token is on.

So for your example above, you'd have a second field named someField_indexed with content:

```
[1_Value1, 2_Value2, 3_Value3, 4_Value4]
[1_Value1, 2_Value3, 3_Value4, 4_Value5]
[1_Value1, 2_Value3, 3_Value3, 4_Value4]
```

The resulting facet would then be:

```
1_Value1: 3
2_Value2: 1
2_Value3: 2
3_Value3: 2
3_Value4: 1
4_Value4: 2
4_Value5: 1
```

Remove everything up to and including the first `_` when you're displaying the contents from the facets. It'll also allow you to filter properly on the location of the value (i.e. only display documents that have Value3 in the second location, by using `fq=someField_indexed:2_Value3`.